# AngularJS Multidimensional array Order By

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional Array that I am parsing to JSON and I would like to "order by" in AngularJS. and i am getting this error: Error: [orderBy:notarray] Expected array but received: 13

```
<div ng-repeat="x in thread track by x.Id | orderBy: x.Id">
```

Here is my JSON:

```
{
  "13": {
    "Id": 16,
    "LINK_Id": 16,
    "Attachments": [
      {
        "AttachmentName": "Attachment.jpeg",
        "AttachmentLinkId": 6,
        "LinkType": "Thread",
        "ThreadId": 20
      },
      {
        "AttachmentName": "Attachment.txt",
        "AttachmentLinkId": 7,
        "LinkType": "Thread",
        "ThreadId": 20
      }
    ]
  },
  "16": {
    "Id": 16,
    "LINK_Id": 169
  },
  "19": {
  "Id": 19,
  "LINK_Id": 112
```

}
}

If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There are some limitation and rules while using orderBy [Go through this](http://justinklemm.com/angularjs-filter-ordering-objects-ngrepeat/). `Iterating an Object of Objects (Acting as an Associative Array or Hash)` This title is what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in thread track by x.Id | orderBy: x.Id">
```

With:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in thread | orderBy: 'Id' track by x.Id">
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't sort the array within the $scope (even because as far as I can see, you don't need to sort it dynamically), I would rather sort it in the controller with the sort method built-in Javascript (faster).

For example after the JSON is returned,

```js
angular.module('sample-app', [])

.controller('SampleController', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope) {

  $scope.test = 'Array Sort';

  $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/')
  .then(function(result) {
    
    // Order id DESC (change a and b position for ASC)
    result.data.sort(function(a, b){ 
      return b.id - a.id 
    });
    
    // inject into scope
    $scope.items = result.data;
  });

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sample-app">
  <section ng-controller="SampleController">
    <h3>{{ test }}</h3>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{ item.id }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```